# nvd3 - can't showXAxis(false) if xAxis is visible

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to make a toggleable axis using nvd3s charts, specifically the [line chart example](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/lineChart.html). After running this example, opening the console, and typing `chart.setXAxis(false)` the x axis does not hide. Is there some documentation or some reason why this isn't working? It doesn't seem to work for any boolean either.. once it's true, it's not changeable to false.

Comment: You need to redraw the chart after setting this.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Is there a `chart.redraw()` or some equivalent?

Comment: `chart.update()` I think.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I would suspect that would work, but for some reason when I do `chart.showXAxis(false).update()` it still doesn't change anything. Additionally, I can show a previously hidden axis with no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setXAxis` just tells the chart function whether or not to draw the axis when it draws the chart, it doesn't do anything to the existing axis.  You'd be better off just selecting the axis directly and changing its visibility style.

Given the class names that NVD3 uses for it's axes, to hide the x-axis you would use:

```
d3.select("g.nv-axis.nv-x").style("visibility", "hidden")
```

That hides the axis, but doesn't delete it, so you can easily re-show it again (without updating the chart) with the same select statement but visibility style `visible`.

Comment: I see. This just goes back to my original question of "why can I show an axis with `.setAxisVisible(true)`, but not hide one with `.setAxisVisible(false)`?" I haven't yet tried it with other booleans like `useInteractiveGuideline`, but will I have to do a similar workaround for those? For reference, I'm making a chart editor, so anything goes.

Comment: When you update a chart, the chart functions (including the axis function) select the relevant elements and update them if they exist or create them if they don't.  If you turn off the axis function after initializing a chart, your axis won't get updated, but it won't by default be removed.  You could create an issue report in the NVD3 github to suggest they add that behaviour, if you want -- it would really just be a couple lines of code.

Comment: @AmeilaBR I definitely have asked them about it, but their github is less active than I had hoped it would be. Would it be a few lines of code on their end? I wouldn't mind forking and submitting a pull request (so I can still use the code in the meantime).

Comment: You could probably put together a decent pull request without too much work.  You'd just have to go through, and everywhere that has `if(showXAxis){...}` (or Y), add an `else{ g.select('.nv-x.nv-axis').selectAll('*').remove();}`.  Just make sure the syntax of the select statement matches the previous select statement.  You could optionally add in a transition to fade the elements to zero opacity before removal.

Comment: Thank you. I'll work that out and hopefully submit a pull request later today. As such, this answer is also correct for the use case, but I think if I make this change I can just do as I would expect to.